# For a failed IP Warming implementation, what's the recourse?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm not really versed in deliverability, but, for an IP Warming plan that has gone poorly (customer gained negative reputation due to not following best practices for IP Warming), what, if any, is the recourse?  New IP and try again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New IP is a good way to clean the slate, but it's costly.
IP Reputation ratings have a long lag time.  If you're not in the "black" category or black-listed, there's still hope.

You need to have the customer think about what campaigns are closest to transactional emails that are VERY timely and applicable.  ESPs will continue to inject some emails into inbox to see what users are doing with messages.